# Using jquery function from within PHP variable string

Tags: php, jquery, function, onclick

I am trying to create a calendar with PHP and when I click on each date, it *triggers* a *jquery function*. However, to create the calendar, I am *concatenating strings in a variable and echoing it*.  And I am trying to use an onClick event to trigger a function in jquery from within the string in the variable.

*The variable is as below*

```
$calendar .= "<td class='day' rel='$date'><div onClick='getdwatt($batch,$currentDay,$mo)'>$currentDay</div></td>";
```

However, this is not working I guess because the variables  in function **getdwatt()** is not in quotes. This is where I am getting stuck. How to do the quotes for this.

Any help is appreciated in advance.

EDIT

The output on view:source is

```
<td class='day' rel='02/03/67'><div onClick='getdwatt(12,Monday,June)'>Monday</div></td>
```

And Jquery error in Chrome tools is saying the output variable value (Monday) in the function is not defined.

I guess the problem is there as it is not resulting in quotes.

How should I resolve this  ?

Comment: Have you viewed the source of your web page and confirmed this printed out correctly?

Comment: dd error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: @JayBlanchard have edited the question to show the view source output and further issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can imagine that your variables `$batch`, `$currentDay` and `$mo` are strings, in this case, you need to wrap these with single quotes when you use their values as parameter.

```php
$calendar .= "<td class=\"day\" rel=\"{$date}\"><div onClick=\"getdwatt('{$batch}', '{$currentDay}', '{$mo}')\">{$currentDay}</div></td>";
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: Just added a short comment to it :)